# BigQuery jdbc driver "missing dataset name"

Tags: google-bigquery

We are trying to use Cognos to access BigQuery using the Simba BigQuery JDBC driver.  We do not want to fully qualify table names in our SELECTs, because we want a single report/model definition to query against different ProjectId/Datasets (e.g., DEV and QA).

There is a parameter called DefaultDataset which can be added to the JDBC URL, but when added I still get "Table name  cannot be resolved: dataset name is missing."  Clearly that's because it's not prefixing  with ProjectId.Dataset. or even Dataset..

Is it possible to set a Default Dataset in the JDBC URL such that table names don't have to be qualified with the Dataset name; rather the Dataset name will be prefixed onto the table name automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The version of the JDBC driver I had previously installed appears to have been prior to 1.1.6 where the DefaultDataset parameter was introduced.  I downloaded the latest driver (1.1.8) and the DefaultDateset parameter now works like a charm.